# how to get description value for object as it as in apex

Tags: apex, soql

EX : i have  record in account  called

```
name :Test123
description :test1
test2
test3
```

now if i Query on Accout [select description from account where name =:Test123];

```
             now i am getting test1 test2 test3 single line 

But i should show test1
                  test2
                  test3  this format.
```

Comment: Where are you trying to display this field? We need more context to be able to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Salesforce standard long text field data type automatically displays format which user enters

Answer (score 0):

@Prasanth, You must do some string manipulations on the Description value.

```
String s = acc.description;    
//Split the string by ' '(space)  
String[] arr = s.split(' ');  
for(String a:arr)  
{  
    //append it with newline  
    System.debug(a+'\n');  
}
```

Comment: Some of Records user will stacked in Spec section fields

Comment: name :Test123
description :test1 test123
                   test2
                   test3 so at this condition your solution will fail

Comment: @Prasanth, why would it fail? it would split all the 4 strings by space and display them one after another in a new line. Have you tried it ?